# Sequence estimate and regular variation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Consider the two matrices
$$
    M_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &
        1 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad M_{2}
    = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 &
        1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We define a sequence $(\mathcal{L}_k)_{k\geq 1}$ of sets of
three-dimensional vectors as follows:
$$
    \mathcal{L}_1 =
    \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}\right\},\quad
    \mathcal{L}_2 =
    \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\right\},\quad
    \mathcal{L}_{k}= \{M_1 \mathbf{v} \,:\, \mathbf{v}\in
    \mathcal{L}_{k-1}\}\cup \{M_{2} \mathbf{v} \,:\, \mathbf{v}\in
    \mathcal{L}_{k-2}\}\quad\text{for $k\geq 3$}.
$$
We then define the
sequences $(\lambda_k)_{k\geq 1}$ and $(\tau_n)_{n\geq 1}$ to be
$$
    \lambda_k = \sum_{(a,b,c)\in \mathcal{L}_k} \frac{1}{abc}
    \quad\text{and}\quad
    \tau_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k.
$$

> I need to prove that $(\tau_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is slowly varying.

Some remarks.

1. The condition $\lambda_k = o\left(\frac{\log^2 k}{k}\right)$ for
   $k\rightarrow +\infty$ implies the result, as follows from Theorem 1.5.4 of Bingham, Goldie and Teugel's book [Regular variation](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/regular-variation/A71D6C4A65CFC1806E1DB7109128A358).
2. It can be shown that $\tau_n \gtrsim \log^2n$ and that $\tau_n$ is slowly varying if and only if $\frac{\tau_{2n}}{\tau_n}\rightarrow 1$. As a consequence, the result is also implied by $\frac{\tau_{2n}-\tau_n}{\log^2n}\rightarrow 0$.

My attempt to prove the result follows the second remark: in particular I arranged the terms of $\tau_{2n}-\tau_n$ to try to ease the estimates, I thought to have a proof, but then I found a mistake I am not able to manage. Thus I wonder whether there is a clever way of thinking to this problem from other points of view I didn't consider. Any help would be very appreciated.

---

I recall here the definition of regular variation for sequences.

> **Definition.**     A sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is said to be *regularly varying
>         of index* $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ if for all $c>0$ we have
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{\lfloor cn\rfloor}}{a_n} = c^\alpha.
> $$
>   If $\alpha=0$ the sequence is called *slowly varying*.